# What is an example of a finite centerless group with at least 3 generators?

Tags: gr.group-theory

I need one to test a theory. There are probably many, but I can't seem to think of a single one. My guess is examples are pretty big.

Is there a systematic way to find such examples? Are there databases one can go through to find these things?

Comment: Are you thinking of *finite* groups?

Comment: Finite. I'll change it.

Comment: Can't you take products of simple groups?

Comment: A direct product of simple groups can be 2-generated. 

Comment: A direct product of enough copies of a given FSG is not 2-generated. 

Comment: Yes, Wiegold proved that the number of generators of $G^n$ where $G$ is a finite simple group grows with $n$. But the growth is as $\log n$. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The group $S_3\wr ({\mathbb Z}_2 \times  {\mathbb Z}_2 \times {\mathbb Z}_2)$ where $S_3$ is the symmetric group with 6 elements, ${\mathbb Z}_2$ is the group with 2 elements, $\wr$ is the wreath product.

The fact that it does not have a center is proved by inspection. The fact that it needs at least 3 generators follows from the fact that ${\mathbb Z}_2^3$ is its quotient. There are lots of similar examples of course.

**Update.**  In general , if you take any centerless group $G$ and any group $H$ that needs at least 3 generators, then the wreath product $G\wr H$ has both properties (is centerless and needs at least 3 generators). Another way to construct examples is (as Derek Holt comment below shows) to take any centerless finite group $G$ with nontrivial abelianization and take $G\times G\times G$.

Comment: Isn't that written $S_3\wreath\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: $A\wr B$ is the semidirect product of $A^B$ and $B$ where $B$ acts on the direct power $A^B$ by permuting components of vectors. There is a competing notation for the same thing $B\wr A$ used by some dynamics people. But the original (I think due Kaluzhnin and Krasner) is as above. Note that ${\mathbb Z} \wr S_3$ has a center, consisting of constant vectors in the base, also it is not that trivial to show that this wreath product needs 3 generators. 

Comment: Why not just $S_3^3$ ?

Comment: @Mark: So the group you have in mind is the semidirect product of $(S_3)^{\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2}$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$, a group of order $3!^8\cdot 8$?

Comment: @Derek: Yes, of course. I just mentioned the first group that came to mind. 

Comment: @Mariano: Yes, $3!=6$. 

Comment: «$3!=6$»? How is that related to my question trying to know exactly what group you were talking about?

Comment: @Mariano: Your computation is absolutely correct. 

Answer (score 13):

The smallest example has order 18. It has a normal elementary abelian subgroup $N$ of order 9, and an element $t$ of order 2 such that $txt=x^{-1}$ for all $x \in N$.

Comment: More generally, an extension of an elementary abelian 3-group $N$ of order $3^r$ by an element of order 2 that inverts everything in $N$ is the smallest example of a centreless group that needs $r+1$ generators.

Answer (score -1):

I can't prove this, but the Rubik's cube group might work.

Update: so this doesn't work.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Why do you think so? In any case, gap tells me that the center is cyclic of order $2$ (I'm using the generators from http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/rubik.html)

Comment: The non trivial central permutation is the one which flips the middle cube of each side. Cute.

Comment: A quick calculation in GAP or Magma also shows that this group is 2-generated.

Comment: @Derek, how did you check? I tried `GQuotients(FreeGroup(2), G : findall := false)` with G is the cube group module its center (which is centerless) but it seems to take forever---I am pretty sure there are faster ways to do this?

Comment: @Mariano:
gap> G = Subgroup(G, [Random(G), Random(G)] );
true

The probability of this returning true seems to be about 0.55.


Comment: Hmm. I should have thought of that :/
